# `unnest_longer` two columns as once?

Tags: r, tidyr

I have a dataframe with two sets of columns `v` and `t` amongst others.

```r
  library(tidyverse)
(df <-   
tibble(id = 1, 
       v1 = 1, v2 = 2, v3 = 3,
       t1 = "a", t2 = "b", t3 = "c"
       )
)
#> # A tibble: 1 × 7
#>      id    v1    v2    v3 t1    t2    t3   
#>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <chr> <chr> <chr>
#> 1     1     1     2     3 a     b     c
```

I want my output to be three rows long. I think one way I can do this is by nesting the similar columns, and `unnest_longer`. But this is not allowed.

```r
  ## unnest_longer can't handle multiple cols
df %>% 
  nest(v = c(v1, v2, v3),
       t = c(t1, t2, t3)) %>% 
  unnest_longer(c("v", "t"))
#> Error: Must extract column with a single valid subscript.
#> x Subscript `var` has size 2 but must be size 1.
```

Is it possible to `unnest_longer` multiple columns at once?

Comment: Use `unnest` i.e. `df %>% 
   nest(v = c(v1, v2, v3),
        t = c(t1, t2, t3)) %>% unnest(c(v, t))`.  Not clear about what you expect as output

Comment: In `unnest_longer`, the documentation says `col- List-column to extract components from.`.  so, it must be a single column, whereas `unnest` argument is `cols`

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation of `?unnest_longer` takes only a single `col`umn

> .col, col -
> List-column to extract components from.

whereas the argument in `unnest` is `cols` (which can unnest more than one column)

Perhaps, the OP wanted to use `pivot_longer` instead of `nest/unnest` i.e. reshape to 'long' format by specifying the `cols` without the 'id' column, return the `.value` and capture the non digits (`\\D+`) in the column name as `names_pattern`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>%
     pivot_longer(cols = -id, names_to = ".value", 
        names_pattern = "^(\\D+).*")
# A tibble: 3 × 3
#     id     v t    
#  <dbl> <dbl> <chr>
#1     1     1 a    
#2     1     2 b    
#3     1     3 c
```